# Como especificarle al servidor la ruta origen de un archivo local

Tags: php, file

quisiera saber como especificarle al servidor que la ruta que le indico es de mi computadora y no del mismo servidor, lo que tengo es un formulario en html que lee un archivo .txt y posteriormente lo manda a un archivo php para que lea el archivo e inserte los datos del .txt en la base de datos, haciendo pruebas en servidor local de apache funciona a la perfeccion pero al montarlo al servidor no encuentra la ruta, ¿Como podria indicarle que la ruta es de mi computadora?

**Este es mi form...**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Sync_up.php">
<input type="file" accept='.txt' name="dir" id="dir">
<br>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Sync up" /></p>
</form>
```

**y este mi archivo de php**

```
<?php

 echo (String)$_FILES['dir']['name']; 


 $ruta='C://Asistencias//'.$_POST['dir']['name'];
 echo "         ";
echo $ruta; 

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "thinkine_SEO", "3306");

$lineas = file($ruta);

foreach ($lineas as $linea_num => $linea)
{
    $datos = explode("|",$linea);

    $id = trim($datos[0]);
    $fecha = trim($datos[1]);
    $hora = trim($datos[2]);
    $status = trim($datos[3]);

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO asistencias(idAlumno,fecha,hora,status) VALUES('$id','$fecha','$hora','$status')";
    $conexion->query($consulta);
}

?>
```

Comment: Tu servidor es windows? Si es linux no va a funcionar esta ruta `$ruta='C://Asistencias//'.$_POST['dir']['name'];`. Tienes que especificarle en la raíz pero de tu servidor. Algo así `'Asistencias/'.$_POST['dir']['name'];` Esta carpeta debe estar en htdocs. Esa es la raíz de php y no te dará problemas.

Comment: El servidor es un host, la ruta me funciona bien en local pero al montarlo al servidor es cuando tengo el problema, aunque especifique la ruta con la ip de mi maquina el servidor en internet sigue sin encontrar la ruta

Comment: Ho! Estas comunicandote entre servidores! No puedes hacerlo así. Tienes que mandar una petición post desde tu servidor a tu pc. (que tiene php) y recivirlo en `miIp.com/miArchivoLocal.php` Y Mi archivo local tendria que responder a `www,miServidor.com/miArchivoQueEscuchaDesdeLocal.php`. Esa es mi idea. De otra manera expondrías tus archivos a todo mundo!.

Comment: Talvez alguien tenga una mejor manera. Yo es la que conozco.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas pude solucionarlo trabajándolo en local y haciendo remota la llamada a la base de datos de mi servidor.

Comment: Si tuvieras oportunidad podrías publicar la respuesta con la solución que encontraste.